# How can I filter list by dataframe in python?

Tags: python, list, pandas, numpy, dataframe

How can I filter list by dataframe in python?

For example, I have list `L = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and dataframe `df`:

```
Name Value
   a     0
   a     1
   b     2
   d     3
```

The result should be `['a', 'b']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = df.loc[df['Name'].isin(L), 'Name'].unique().tolist()
print (a)
['a', 'b']
```

Or:

```
a = np.intersect1d(L, df['Name']).tolist()
print (a)
['a', 'b']
```

**timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

L = ['a', 'b', 'c']

#jezrael 1
In [163]: %timeit (df.loc[df['Name'].isin(L), 'Name'].unique().tolist())
The slowest run took 5.53 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 774 µs per loop

#jezrael 2    
In [164]: %timeit (np.intersect1d(L, df['Name']).tolist())
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.81 ms per loop

#divakar
In [165]: %timeit ([i for i in L if i in df.Name.tolist()])
1000 loops, best of 3: 393 µs per loop

#john galt 1
In [166]: %timeit (df.query('Name in @L').Name.unique().tolist())
The slowest run took 5.30 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 2.36 ms per loop

#john galt 2    
In [167]: %timeit ([x for x in df.Name.unique() if x in L])
The slowest run took 5.32 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 182 µs per loop
```

Comment: I guess would be nice to see more elements in `L` too than just `3` :)

Comment: sure, I add small data because OP says small df. give me a sec

Comment: @Dmitry - what is real size of your data? what is size of your L?

Comment: About 1000 records in `df`, `L` and result, length is about 30 characters. But the most important problem is that actual data are like the following: `aaa` in the `df` and `aaa.z` in the `L` (with '.z' extension). So, I can't use some methods like `[i for i in l if i in df.Name.tolist()]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one -

```
[i for i in l if i in df.Name.tolist()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [303]: df
Out[303]: 
  Name  Value
0    a      0
1    a      1
2    b      2
3    d      3

In [304]: l = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [305]: [i for i in l if i in df.Name.tolist()]
Out[305]: ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Is it faster than `jezrael's` solution?

Comment: @Dmitry Test for yourself? Or provide a dataset for timing?

Comment: I don't have so much data. Just curious :) Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: I add timings , really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `query`

```
In [1470]: df.query('Name in @L').Name.unique().tolist()
Out[1470]: ['a', 'b']
```

Or,

```
In [1472]: [x for x in df.Name.unique() if x in L]
Out[1472]: ['a', 'b']
```